# Must $P$ be a circle?

Tags: convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $P$ be a convex curve inside a circle $C$, such that for every point $x$ on $C$, there are two perpendicular tangent lines of $P$ go through $x$. Must be $P$ be a circle?

If we change the condition "two tangent lines are perpendicular" by "the angle between them is $\frac{\pi}{3}$", the problem become easy: Let $x$ be a point on $C$, let two tangent lines of $P$ which go through $x$ intersect $C$ again at $y,z$, then the two tangent lines of $P$ which go through $y$ and $z$ respectively but not $x$ are either parallel, which can't be because a convex curve $P$ can't have two parallel tagent lines such that $P$ is not between them, or they are coincide, which means $xyz$ is an equilateral triangle. So for every equilateral triangle which vertices on $C$, all of their edges are tangent to $P$ and it is easy to see that $P$ must be a circle.

[image]

But the problem is not simple if the angle between them is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or more generally $\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{2n},m,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$. The reason is that if you try to find two tangent lines of $P$ which parallel such that $P$ is not between them by above way, they are actually always coincide.

Comment: @daw there is also the case that they form a rectangle, which $P$ can't be a circle in this case. So basically we want to know that must those vertices form a square.

Comment: Consider the [director circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle) of an ellipse.

Comment: @Blue thank you very much. You can answer this question to receive 50 reputation. I would happy if you can solve the general case

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the general case", so I'll let someone else take up that task and leave the bounty to them. Good luck!

Comment: @Blue I guess in the general case the angle is $\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{2n}$, $m,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$.

Answer (score 3):

For the case where the tangents are perpendicular the inner curve may be an ellipse. To wit:

1. Inscribe a square in the circle
2. Define the center of the ellipse to match that of the circle and square and the foci to both lie on one diagonal of the square.
3. Set the major axis of the ellipse (sum of distances from the two foci) so that it's tangent to one side of the square, in which case by symmetry it will be tangent to all four sides of the square.
4. We have defined the tangents to be perpendicular from just four points on the circle, but in fact the tangents from *all* points on the circle to the ellipse will be perpendicular. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle).

We may parametrize the ellipse in the following manner ($r$ is the radius of the outer circle, $\theta$ is any constant between $0$ and $\pi/4$):

Semimajor axis = $r\cos\theta$

Semiminor axis = $r\sin\theta$

Eccentrivity = $\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}/\cos\theta$

The reader may want to identify the limiting construction where $\theta\to0$.

Comment: And it can be non-ellipse curve as well.

Comment: Possibly, although the term "director circle" is associated with an ellipse. We may also have a hyperbola _outside_ the circle with perpendicular tangents to the circle, if the eccentricity is less than the square root of 2.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Oscar's answer:

The authors of

*Cieślak, Waldemar; Mozgawa, Witold*, [**On curves with circles as their isoptics**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00010-021-00828-4), Aequationes Math. 96, No. 3, 653-667 (2022). [ZBL1497.53005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1497.53005).

gave a complete characterization (in terms of Fourier series of the associated periodic functions $p(t)$) of $C^1$-smooth closed convex planar curves $P$ for which the **isoptic** curve is a round circle (your circle $C$). In particular, there are non-conic curves $P$ with this property.  As a specific example, they give the curve $P$ in the complex plane with the parameterization
$$
z(t)= p(t) e^{it} + i p'(t)e^{it}, t\in [0, 2\pi],
$$
where
$$
p(t)= \sqrt{a \sin^2(3t) + b \cos^2(9t) +c,} 
$$
for fixed values of the parameters $a, b, c$.

Comment: Edited: the reference gives $p$ as the square root of what was originally written.